# Strange behavior of SDL_GetKeyState()

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to write a Pong clone in C++ using SDL. Basically, I wrote a simple engine that takes care of rendering and updating

```
void Player::update(Uint32 ticks, SDL_Event *event, Uint8 *keys)
{

if(keys[SDLK_UP])
{
    if(m_bounds.y > 0)
        m_bounds.y -= 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f);
}

else if(keys[SDLK_DOWN])
{
    if(m_bounds.y < (windowInfo.getHeight() - m_bounds.h))
        m_bounds.y += 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f);
}
}
```

The problem is that when I press the UP key, everything works like a charm, but when I press the DOWN key, it doesn't work at all. I tried everything and after a couple of hours I noticed, that when I remove the ticks and add just 2.0f it works, but I don't know why, since the conditional for the UP key looks exactly the same, except it adds, instead of substracting. I've been trying to deal with this problem a couple of hours and still have not solved it. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

For completeness, I'm attaching some code that calls the Player::update function, so that you know a bit more.

```
void Engine::update()
{
++m_numOfFrames;
m_elapsedTime = SDL_GetTicks() - m_startTime;

while(SDL_PollEvent(&m_event))
{
    if(m_event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        m_isRunning = false;
    }
}

if(m_keys[SDLK_ESCAPE])
{
    m_isRunning = false;
}

for(Entity *entity : m_entities)
{
    entity->update(m_elapsedTime, &m_event, m_keys);
}

m_startTime = SDL_GetTicks();
SDL_PumpEvents();
}
```

EDIT:
I edited the code a bit to see all the values, the code looks like this now:

```
if(keys[SDLK_UP])
{
    if(m_bounds.y > 0)
    {
        m_bounds.y -= 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f);
        std::cout << 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f) << " value of Y:" << m_bounds.y << std::endl;
    }
}

else if(keys[SDLK_DOWN])
{
    if(m_bounds.y < (windowInfo.getHeight() - m_bounds.h))
    {
        m_bounds.y += 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f);
        std::cout << 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f) << " value of Y:" << m_bounds.y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The result in console are pretty much the same for both, except for the DOWN conditional, the value of `m_bounds.y` doesn't change at all, it's always the same, although it's been added a line higher. The error must be on this line:

```
m_bounds.y += 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f);
```

Comment: I would guess both _Up_ and _Down_ are pressed at the same time, at least to the program... How do you fill up your `m_keys`?

Comment: I do fill m_keys with this code `m_keys = SDL_GetKeyState(0);` And not, they are not pressed at the same time, I tried lots of pressing variations and nothing changed.

Comment: Insufficient debug output in your `Player::update` function. There's loads more investigation can be done

Comment: @michy04: Does it work if you position the `Player` at coordinates `(0,0)`?

Comment: Yes I did a bit of debugging, I tried this `std::cout << 2.0f * (ticks / 1000.0f) << std::endl;` to make sure the value of the expression is not null, and it is not, it prints out values in range from 0.002 - 0.012

Comment: @K-ballo No it doesn't. I also tried commenting the conditionals out to see if there is no logic error and it did not work either.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of float precision problems.

Comment: Do you reset the keys element when SDLK_UP is released?

Comment: @Hans Passant Hopefully not

Comment: @iccthedral What do you mean? SDL_PumpEvents? I'm not that exprienced with SDL? Is it SDL_PumpEvents or anything else?

Comment: @michy04 What is the type of m_bounds? Is it a SDL_Rect? If it is realize that x and y are Sint16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finished the game a couple of weeks ago and I thought I should share what coused this strange behavior, just in case someone would run into the same or similiar problem.

Basically, `talles` is right in his comment, the problem was that X and Y variables were of type Sint16, it caused some problems - the solution was simple - **I had created a struct Vector2f and mapped the floats to Sint16.**